# how can I change between modes with my button

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I created 2 drawing modes but they draw at the same time but i want them to work seperateley so i created a button but dont know how to define the mode change for the button to work

how can I define my mode change so I can change between different drawing modes eg freehandmode, circlemode so they dont work at the same time

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

beni=Screen()
beni.setup(400, 400, 10, 10)
beni.setworldcoordinates(-300, -300, 300, 300)

def mode_change(x, y):



#freehandmode
def freehandmode(x, y):
    t.ondrag(None)
    t.setheading(t.towards(x, y))
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.ondrag(freehandmode)



#circlemode
def draw_circle(x, y):
    beni.onclick(None)
    center = turtle.position()
    turtle.setposition(x, y)
    turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(center) - 90)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(turtle.distance(center))
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.clearstamps()
    beni.onclick(pick_center)

def pick_center(x, y):
    beni.onclick(None)
    turtle.setposition(x, y)
    turtle.stamp()
    beni.onclick(draw_circle)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape('circle')
turtle.shapesize(0.5)
turtle.penup()

beni.onclick(pick_center)


#freehand turtle
t = Turtle('circle')
t.shapesize(1)
t.speed('fastest')
t.ondrag(freehandmode)

#modechange turtle
modechange = Turtle('circle')
modechange.pu()
modechange.shapesize(0.55, 1.45)
modechange.color('black')
modechange.setpos(0, 290)
modechange.onclick(mode_change)

#modebutton
modebutton = Turtle()
modebutton.shapesize(0.25)
modebutton.pu()
modebutton.setpos(-20, 300)
modebutton.setheading(270)
modebutton.pd()
modebutton.fd(20)
modebutton.setheading(0)
modebutton.fd(45)
modebutton.setheading(90)
modebutton.fd(20)
modebutton.setheading(180)
modebutton.fd(45)
modebutton.pu()
modebutton.setpos(-10, 263)
modebutton.setheading(0)
modebutton.color('green')
modebutton.write('Modi')
modebutton.hideturtle()

beni.mainloop()
```

Comment: You tagged this [python-2.7] but treating `mainloop` as a method of the screen keeps it from running in Python 2.  It runs fine in Python 3.  Also, make the body of `mode_change()` a `pass` statement so this code will at least run as-is.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly a matter of accounting -- you need to explicitly list steps necessary to disable one turtle and enable the other every time you switch modes.  And you need to keep track of the current mode.  Here's my rework and simplification of your (actually, largely *my*) code to do this:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop

def mode_change(x, y):
    global mode

    if mode == 'freehand':
        # disable freehand
        freehand.ondrag(None)
        freehand.hideturtle()

        # enable circle
        screen.ontimer(lambda: screen.onclick(pick_center))  # so screen doesn't inherit *this* click
        mode = 'circle'
    else:
        # disable circle
        screen.onclick(None)

        # enable freehand
        freehand.ondrag(freehandmode)
        freehand.showturtle()
        mode = 'freehand'

# freehand mode
def freehandmode(x, y):
    freehand.ondrag(None)

    freehand.setheading(freehand.towards(x, y))
    freehand.goto(x, y)

    freehand.ondrag(freehandmode)

# circle mode
def draw_circle(x, y):
    screen.onclick(None)

    center = circle.position()
    circle.setposition(x, y)
    circle.setheading(circle.towards(center) - 90)
    circle.pendown()
    circle.circle(circle.distance(center))
    circle.penup()
    circle.clearstamps()

    screen.onclick(pick_center)

def pick_center(x, y):
    screen.onclick(None)

    circle.setposition(x, y)
    circle.stamp()

    screen.onclick(draw_circle)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(400, 400)

mode = 'freehand'

circle = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
circle.shapesize(0.5)
circle.speed('fastest')
circle.penup()

freehand = Turtle('circle')
freehand.speed('fastest')
freehand.ondrag(freehandmode)

# modechange turtle
modechange = Turtle('square')
modechange.penup()
modechange.setposition(0, 155)
modechange.pencolor('green')
modechange.write('Modi', align='center')

modechange.shapesize(2.25, 1.0)
modechange.setposition(0, 190)
modechange.onclick(mode_change)

mainloop()
```

Comment: I have one more question- so i created anotther mode its called linemode how can I add that one to the modechange? class Drawer:
    def __init__(self):
       self.drawing = False

    def click(self, x, y):
        if self.drawing:
            turtle.down()
            turtle.goto(x, y)
            self.drawing = False
        else:
            turtle.up()
            turtle.goto(x, y)
            self.drawing = True

d = Drawer()
beni.onclick(d.click)